# jqgrid hide columns on edit form based on an other column value

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In a jqgrid, i have columns that are editable only if a certain column has a given value, is it possible to show / hide those columns on the add / edit form based on that column (select) value ?

I've already been through the aftershowform function, is there any other way to do it ?
using aftershowform all fields are shown at first and then made hidden with an ugly render effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide/show any editable column inside of `beforeShowForm` or `afterShowForm` callback. It's important to understand that jqGrid fill the form with **all editable columns**. The form contains rows. Every row have id which build based on the `name` of editable column. The row id have `"tr_"` prefix which are appended to the column name (the value of `name` property in `colModel`). So if you need to hide the column having `name: "Name"` then you can do

```
beforeShowForm: function ($form) { $form.find("#tr_Name").hide(); }
```

or just

```
beforeShowForm: function () { $("#tr_Name").hide(); }
```

(see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3405961/315935)).

To get rowid which will be currently editing you can use

```
var rowid = $form.find("#id_g").val();
```

or

```
var rowid = $("#id_g").val();
```

(see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17009580/315935)). The strange id value "id_g" is the id of hidden element which will be placed by jqGrid in every editing form. Alternatively you can use

```
var rowid = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
```

because the value from `selrow` also contains the rowid of the current editing row.

To test content of another column before hiding/showing the row you can use `getCell`. In case of `datatype: "local"` (or in case of usage `loadonce: true`) you can get object with full row data using `getLocalRow` method.